# MPI FOX algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mpi

So I have to program an MPI application in C. The application should be a simulation of FOX algorithm.

I think I've searched the internet for ALL possible places to find a functioning version of FOX algorithm to get the understanding of the code.

Any idea where I might find it? Maybe just an animation of the functions of the algorithm?

Comment: A quick search for ["+fox +matrix +algorithm"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%2Bfox+%2Bmatrix+%2Balgorithm) brings up quite a few example including tutorials with C/MPI code examples.

Comment: Ok - any idea where a working source code could be found?

Comment: http://www.caam.rice.edu/~caam520/Topics/ParallelAlgorithms/LinearAlgebra/fox.c

Comment: thanks - well it makes some kind of strange message....

qwer.c:20:5: error: unknown type name ‘MPI_COMM’
qwer.c:21:5: error: unknown type name ‘MPI_COMM’
qwer.c:22:5: error: unknown type name ‘MPI_COMM’
qwer.c:33:9: error: unknown type name ‘LOCAL_MATRIX_T’
qwer.c:34:9: error: unknown type name ‘LOCAL_MATRIX_T’
qwer.c:35:9: error: unknown type name ‘LOCAL_MATRIX_T’

I call the c-file qwer.c just for the ease of it.....

Comment: It looks like that example is incomplete and is actually from the book [parallel programming with MPI](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GufgfWSHt28C&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=GRID_INFO_T+LOCAL_MATRIX_T&source=bl&ots=6kRp29sSmk&sig=rhLI5O43jiqJaHvMtWKvJqQXNm0&hl=en&ei=5U7WTunmJcvoOYiAgUk&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=GRID_INFO_T%20LOCAL_MATRIX_T&f=false). Read the rest of the chapter for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the deep dark depths of the internets:

http://web.mst.edu/~ercal/387/MPI/ppmpi_c/chap07/fox.c

This is somewhat of a cryptic rendition of Fox's algorithm using MPI & C, but it works none the less.